# Neovim: "E492: Not an editor command"

Tags: neovim

I am trying to set up Neovim as an IDE for data science. I want to be able to execute highligted code blocks in a terminal session running IPython or R. For this I want to install the plugin [iron.nvim](https://github.com/Vigemus/iron.nvim).

The official readme suggests, that the terminal session can be launched with the command `:IronRepl`, but when I do this I get the error: `E492: Not an editor command: IronRepl`.

I've settled on using `lazy.nvim` as my package manager and have managed to install and apply a colourscheme correctly. This tells me, I am mostly doing this correctly.

I have bootstrapped `lazy.nvim` in `~/.config/nvim/init.lua` as described in [the official readme](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim/blob/main/README.md).

In the same file I have specified the location of the plugins-list to be loaded:

```
require("lazy").setup({
        import = "plugins"
    })
```

In  `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/plugins.lua` I have specified:

```
return {
    'hkupty/iron.nvim'
}
```

Running `:Lazy` reveals that the plugin has been installed correctly (and is in fact loaded). Running `h: Iron` opens the help pages, which also suggests it is correctly installed.

Any thoughts on how I can resolve this error?

I installed iron.nvim and tried to open a terminal session with the plugin as suggested in the official readme. I got an error message saying: `E492: Not an editor command: IronRepl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Welcome to stack overflow!

You're almost there! Take a look into the [How to configure](https://github.com/Vigemus/iron.nvim#how-to-configure) part of the README.
The important lines are:

```lua
local iron = require("iron.core")

iron.setup {
    -- ...
}
```

The `iron.setup` *function* does the actual plugin-preparation which includes
the commands which you'll be able to use afterwards. So you need to change your
config as follows:

Instead of having

```lua
return {
    'hkupty/iron.nvim'
}
```

you'll need to change it to:

```lua
return {
    {
        'hkupty/iron.nvim',
        -- note that `init` will disable lazy-loading!
        init = function()
            local iron = require("iron.core")

            iron.setup({
                -- add the other options if you want
                config = {}
            })
        end
    }
}
```

Alternatively (which I suggest) you can make use of lazy-file-separation
"feature" which allows you to declare a plugin in a separate file :)
Take a look into [Lazy's README](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim#-structuring-your-plugins) for this case or you can take a look into [my
plugin directory](https://github.com/TornaxO7/my_configs/tree/master/nvim/lua/plugins).

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! Your solution worked, but I want to understand why.

It seems to me that "init" is a variable, that gets a function assigned to it - correct? 
Since the iron.nvim documentation didn't mention this - how could I have figured this out? Do all plugins expect this? How do you know which arguments are required?

Comment: I read this `init` "variable" from [this list](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim#-plugin-spec). This table/list includes all attributes of the table which you're returning inside of your `return` table. Take a look into the [example from lazy.nvim](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim#-plugin-spec).